# What does favoriting a dye do?

Tags: guild-wars-2

In the dye panel you have an option to right click dyes to favorite colors. Other than moving to the favorite dye section at the top, does favoriting a dye do anything else?

I had heard a rumor that favoriting a dye would allow you to share the color across your other characters. I naturally was curious and tried it but it didn't work.

Comment: I really want an "Eyedropper"-esque tool, instead of having to figure out how to select the dye I want from the dye I've already applied.

Comment: @RavenDreamer That does sound like a nice functionality. For now I typically have my armor dyed the colors that are in my favorites so I usually have no issue knowing which colors are the ones I am currently using (namely Hot Pink and Lemonade on my manly warrior ;) )

Comment: I just hover over my applied dye, and it tells me the colour name? (Of course, you then have to hunt it down in the dye list...) (Alternatively, right-mouse clicking on applied dye favourites it, so you know what it is right away, and then you can just unfavourite it after)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Favoriting a dye does only what you said, it moves it to the top of your dye panel so you can easily pick it out from other dyes. As you stated, favoriting dyes does *not* allow you to share it across your characters. Dyes are currently character bound.

Comment: As an update note to this question and answer, dyes were changed to be account-bound in the April 2014 feature pack.